# NodeJs calculation gone wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have if statement like:

```
if((gotPrice * price.value).toFixed(0) >= answers.MINIMUM_BUY_AMOUNT) {
   ...
}
```

Results are

`(gotPrice * price.value).toFixed(0) = 0`

and

`answers.MINIMUM_BUY_AMOUNT = 200`

Then it fall to `true`! not sure in what world `0` is greater or equal to `200`!!

I also tried this way but results was the same

```
if((gotPrice * price.value).toFixed(0) >= Number(answers.MINIMUM_BUY_AMOUNT).toFixed(0)) {
   ...
}
```

sample:

```js
var x = 0.3431;
var y = 1.5467;
var z = '200';
console.log((x * y).toFixed(0) >= z); // false (but in my case says true!)
```

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: `toFixed()` returns a `string`. If you just want to remove decimal places use `Math.round` or `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor` whatever fits best for your situation

Comment: @derpirscher ok i'll try that but in meanwhile my `answers.MINIMUM_BUY_AMOUNT` is also string i guess isn't it?

Comment: Why are you calculating with strings? Use numbers instead. for strings, `<` and `>` are evaluated lexicographic. So `"9"` will always be greater than `"10"`

Comment: exactly that's part of issue, that's why i shared sample code with `var z = '200';`

Comment: And for your second snippet. I edited your post to be runable, and it obviously says `false` in the console ... So you probably have other values (or a node version which gets such basic calculations wrong, which I very much doubt). And also be aware, that `toFixed` uses rounding, ie something like `2.678.toFixed(2)` will give `'3'`

Comment: so this `Math.floor(gotPrice * price.value) >= Number(answers.MINIMUM_BUY_AMOUNT)` would be correct way to do it?

Comment: Dependning on yor needs, yes ...

Comment: I  meant `2.678.toFixed(0)` gives `3` of course ... but can't edit that comment anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

ToFixed converts number to string, calculations should be done with numbers

```
var x = 0.3431;
var y = 1.5467;
var z = parseInt('200');

console.log(Math.round(x * y) >= z);
```